# Метод panBy Yandex map API

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть ли ymaps метод по аналогии с google maps panBy(x, y)[пример](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map.panBy)

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, что там в гугл, но похоже на это - [PanTo](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1-dev/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#method_detail__panTo)?